# Error during DEM interpolation for raster grid : data item in gstat object and newdata have different coordinate reference systems

Tags: raster, r

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(gstat)

# load data
dem_points <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "dem_points", verbose = F)
study_area <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "study_area", verbose = F)
  

# Clip dem_points within study area
dem_points_clip <- intersect(dem_points, study_area)

# Obtain extent
dem_bbox <- bbox(dem_points_clip)
# Create raster
dem_rast <- raster(xmn = dem_bbox[1, 1], 
                   xmx = ceiling(dem_bbox[1, 2]),
                   ymn = dem_bbox[2, 1], 
                   ymx = ceiling(dem_bbox[2, 2]))
# Set projection
projection(dem_rast) <- CRS(projection(dem_points_clip))
# Set resolution
res(dem_rast) <- 5


# Compute the interpolation function
dem_interp <- gstat(formula = ALT ~ 1, locations = dem_points_clip,
                    set = list(idp = 0), nmax = 5)

# Obtain interpolation values for raster grid
DEM <- interpolate(dem_rast, dem_interp)

Error in predict.gstat(model, blockvals, debug.level = debug.level, ...) : 
  var1 : data item in gstat object and newdata have different coordinate reference systems
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In proj4string(d$data) :
  CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
2: In proj4string(newdata) :
  CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
```

Note: Both X and Y data are in degrees with same coordinates. EPSG: 4326-WGS 84 CRS is used to make the required shapefile using QGiS.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to debug without a reproducible example. Perhaps it is due to the recent changes in the coordinate reference system handling.

The general approach you are taking works for me with `terra` and with `raster`. But note that I do not use `SpatialPoints*`. `meuse` is a `data.frame` without CRS, and perhaps that helps.

```
library(gstat)
library(sp)
data(meuse)
```

With terra

```
library(terra)   
r <- rast(system.file("ex/test.tif", package="terra"))
mg <- gstat(id = "zinc", formula = zinc~1, locations = ~x+y, data=meuse, 
            nmax=7, set=list(idp = .5))

z <- interpolate(r, mg, debug.level=0)
z <- mask(z, r)
```

And with `raster`

```
library(raster)
rr <- raster(r)
zz <- interpolate(rr, mg, debug.level=0)
zz <- mask(zz, rr)
```

So perhaps you can try

```
m <- as.data.frame(dem_points_clip)
```

And take it from there?

Also, this is a bit odd (you are taking the ceiling of single numbers)

```
dem_bbox <- bbox(dem_points_clip)
dem_rast <- raster(xmn = dem_bbox[1, 1], 
                   xmx = ceiling(dem_bbox[1, 2]),
                   ymn = dem_bbox[2, 1], 
                   ymx = ceiling(dem_bbox[2, 2]))
res(dem_rast) <- 5
```

Instead, you can do

```
 dem_rast <- raster(dem_points_clip, res=5)
```

or use `floor` to expand the extent a bit.

```
 dem_rast <- raster(floor(extent(dem_points_clip)), res=5)
```